# How to Parallelize Kinect AllFramesReady event

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, kinect

I am developing with Kinect and I need to perform a task in the AllFramesReady event.
The task consists in a lot of writing using a `BinaryWriter`.

I know that the frame (Color, Depth, Skeleton) exists for a short time period.

```
using (var imageFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
{
     // Do the heavy task writing tons of bits do a `BinaryWriter`
} // The frame is no longer available :(
```

Is there a way to parallelize it? Or some trick to improve the performance of my code?

Comment: In the 1.6 SDK Examples the `KinectDepthViewer`, in the KinectWpfViewers project, does its depth coloring in a parallel process.  That might be a good place to start.  I'll investigate more too when I'm at my computer where I can access code.

Comment: Thanks, i will investigate it too.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, don't do the heavy lifting in AllFramesReady event handler. My suggestion is: store the Frame information in a queue, then use another thread to write the stored information to disk memory. note that when the rate of entering the queue exceeds the rate of leaving the queue, at some point, you will run out of memory.